# Linked service: SQL Server-2019 to Cosmos DB

Tags: sql-server-2019, linked-server, cosmos-db

I have created linked service for importing data from Azure cosmos DB to on-prem MS-SQL-2019. Services created from SSMS and test connection is successful, but query is getting error.

Query:

```
select * from openquery ( 
linked_service_name,'select * from
cosmos_collection');
```

> Error:  "Error occurred while submitting query text to OLE DB provider "SSISOLEDB" for linked server "linked_service_name"

**Linked service set-up:**

Provider: SQL Server OLE DB

Data Source: User DSN [ Created in ODBC Data source admin ]

Provider String: Secondary key from Cosmos DB

Catalog: Schema name of Cosmos DB

Comment: What happens if you directly run `select * from linked_service_name.DatabaseName.SchemaName.cosmos_collection` ?

Comment: getting "invalid object name linked_service_name.DatabaseName.SchemaName.cosmos_collection " Msg 208 level 16 ,stage 1

Comment: Can you script out your Linked Server object and add the script to your Post?

Comment: Also you didn't literally write the words `DatabaseName` right?...you changed that to name of your Cosmos database? Same for the `SchemaName`.